# How do I access the default SharePoint image library by using the SharePoint REST API for SharePoint Online?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, ms-office, office365

I'm using the info from [Get all files and folders in default document library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605900%28v=office.15%29.aspx#File1) to access the default document library. The resource to access files and folders in the default document library is `GET https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/files`. In a Web browser, the URL is something like this: **https://tenant.sharepoint.com/Documents/**. Now then, I'd like to access the default image library in my SharePoint site. I don't know what the resource URL looks like to access the image library at **https://tenant.sharepoint.com/SiteImages/**.

How do I use the SharePoint REST API to access the default image library with my SharePoint Online site?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/files('SiteImages')/Children
```

Comment: I get a 404 when I try that resource. Thank you for response.